# Skip to Content Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to put a Skip to Content link within my web application, but am having some issues.

Currently I have

```
<asp:LinkButton id="linkSkiptoContent" runat="server" OnClick="linkSKipToContent" Text="Skip to Content"></asp:LinkButton>
```

within the asp page

and an onClick event receiver

```
protected void linkSkipToContent_Click(object sender, EvenArgs e){
    checkbox.Focus();
}
```

I am trying to avoid javascript because users have the option to disable it, which would render the link useless. And I know the checkbox.Focus() works properly, since I stuck it in the Page_Load() method and that worked at intented. However, what happens is clicking the link causes it to be focused after the onClick event completes.

Comment: In order to get a better idea of what "skip to content" means, can you include more of the aspx page?  Does the checkbox need to be focused or do you want the page to scroll to the checkbox?

Comment: Ironically, a .NET LinkButton does not work without JavaScript enabled. You'll need to use something else, like a Button.

Comment: @AlW Here's an overview of what a skip to content link is: http://www.webnauts.net/skip-to-main-content.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print an anchor:

```
<a name="content" />
```

And link to it:

```
<a href="#content">Go to content </a>
```

Don't need JS or serverside stuff for that.